# Api gateway with lambda proxy integration mangles binary output

Tags: aws-lambda, binary-data, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda, written in Java, from which I want to output binary data (namely Excel spreadsheets). I noticed that the data being returned by the Lambda is mutated by Api Gateway. To investigate the problem, I created a simple Lambda which outputs:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {},
  "body": "AOld",
  "isBase64Encoded": true
}
```

This corresponds to the three (hex) bytes:

```
00 E9 5D
```

I then set up an API in Api Gateway. The API consists of a simple method on the root resource, whose integration request is a Lambda Function, with proxy integration, pointing at the above Lambda. I am passing in Content-Type and Accept headers, and the content types being used are marked as Binary media types.
When this passes through API Gateway, however, I get

```
00 EF BF BD 5D
```

Any idea why Api Gateway is mangling my binary output?

Comment: I've tried to replicated this, and I haven't been successful as of yet. Can you confirm that you have redepoyed your API after making changes to your api config?

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being with Postman, which I was using to do my queries. When I did the queries via curl in the command line, the problem went away.